# Blank page when trying to access phpmyadmin

Tags: apache2, phpmyadmin

I would like to access phpmyadmin. I have access it before but, now, I'm just getting a blank page and I really don't get why.

I've installed phpmyadmin using

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

I've run

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

And there added:

```
#Include phpmyadmin: 
 include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

But I was getting a warning when I restart apache, telling me:

> The Alias directive in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf at line 3 will
>   probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.

How can I solve this, so that I can see phpmyadmin interface again, when I do http://localhost/phpmyadmin instead of seeing a blank webpage?

**Dump** -

- I've tried `apt-get remove phpmyadmin` and then `apt-get install phpmyadmin` - still the same blank page. :(
- `/etc/phpmyadmin` - I've chmod o+w permissions to phpmyadmin folder and it's contents. - still the blank page...

Comment: Did you try it before you added `include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`? If not, can you try to remove that line and restart to try again?

Comment: @root45  - Yes I've try it before without that line. And then with it, and now, I've remove that line. :(

Comment: I should have asked this above, but did removing that line get rid of the message "The Alias directive in /etc ... an earlier Alias" that you get when you restart? I think there may be two separate issues here.

Comment: @root45 - Yes. Removing that line, removed the message.

Comment: Can you tell me the owner and group for `/etc/phpmyadmin`? You can `ls -la /etc | grep phpmyadmin`. The user and group will be the third and fourth entries for the line corresponding to `/etc/phpmyadmin`. I think you can also get this from the properties window.

Comment: @root45: `ls -ld /etc/phpmyadmin` is the right way to get a single line of information on a folder.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Thanks. I should really read up on all the flags for common commands like `ls`.

Comment: @root45: drwxr-xrwx 2 root root 4096 2011-08-26 14:17 /etc/phpmyadmin

Comment: Okay, try changing the owner to `www-data` with `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /etc/phpmyadmin`. Do the same for `/var/lib/phpmyadmin` and `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`.

Comment: @root45 - done it. Now I have: `drwxr-xrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 2011-08-26 14:17 /etc/phpmyadmin` - still no luck and the white page still appears.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

To set up the phpmyadmin files, database connections and create the phpmyadmin databases

Comment: I cannot test this any longer. If someone find this answer an answer, please shared and I will mark it as a correct answer. cheers.

Comment: Not working on 15.04 problem still remained.

Comment: very old answer and question but yeah... problem still persists

Answer (score 19):

All the previous answers did not help me, but then I found the solution:

```
apt install php-gettext
```

this fixed `phpmyadmin` white blank page issue.

Comment: After updating from 15.04 to 16.04, I needed to re-install MySQL 5.7 because the attempted upgrade from MySQL 5.6 failed.  After the 5.7 installation, I got a blank page from phpMyAdmin also... spent a great amount of time searching for clues... and this single answer resolved my issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred to me because I modified the php.ini (/etc/php5/apache/php.ini) and introduced a wrong format. Specifically, I needed to upload a bigger file so I modified this line:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

with:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20
```

As you can see, I missed an M. After restarting apache (`sudo service apache2 restart`), I was getting the blank page.

** In general, it might be that a mistake in the php.ini produces a silent (blank page) output in php. **

Answer (score 0):

An old question I know, but I recently had the same problem. Accessing the phpmyadmin url produced a blank white page. The apache logs showed nothing wrong. All response headers were "200 OK".

The problem was simple, I had disabled javascript in the browser.

To fix in firefox, enter the url 'about:config', find the key named 'javascript.enabled' and toggle it true.

In chrome, navigate to Setting > Advanced Settings > Content Settings, scroll down to the Javascript header and toggle the 'Enable javascript' checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

When i changed this inside the config.inc.php:

`$cfg['UploadDir'] = '/tmp';
 $cfg['SaveDir'] = '/tmp';`

to:

`$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';`

and reloaded the page then it worked directly!

Answer (score -1):

My problem was different: the page rendered white but, inspecting the HTML, I could see the login and password fields. The problem was in the space on the HDD:

> No space left on device

Freeing some made phpMyAdmin work again.

Answer (score -1):

I`m not sure if is the same in ubuntu, but for debian 7.0.0 i find a way and my problem was fixed with this :

apt-get install php5-json

I informed from this link :

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=710861;msg=7