# localhost phpmyadmin showing blank page on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, phpmyadmin

I have apache version 2.4.52, MySQL version 8.0 and PHP version 7.4

I have installed phpmyadmin using

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```

While installing i configured phpmyadmin with apache2 and created a phpmyadmin dummy user to access database.

After full installation when i want to access localhost/phpmyadmin it shows blank page.

when i tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58748/blank-page-when-trying-to-access-phpmyadmin) it shows `E: Unable to locate package php-gettext` and rest of the solution does not work for me.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt install php7.4-mysql
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

I'm guessing this will fix yours with PHP 7.4. I had the same issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04.1 except I'm running PHP 8.1, and I had to install php8.1-mysql and restart Apache.

Comment: Thanks @Tacocat for your answer but my problem was **phpmyadmin** version. By default i was installing **phpmyadmin version 5.2.0** but after installing **phpmyadmin version 4.9.10** fixed my issue.

Comment: My phpmyadmin version is also 5.2.0, but I didn't have to revert to the older version - just install the missing package. It's possible it was held back due to the upgrade, but I'm not sure how to tell that now.

Answer (score 0):

In a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.10, just after configured MariaDB client and server, but no apache nor php... with:

`sudo apt install phpmyadmin`

installs apache, php8.1.7 and some other dependencies. But I had blank page .

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72103022/phpmyadmin-blank-white-page-instead-of-login-screen) the suggestion is:

`sudo apt -y install wget php php-cgi php-mysqli php-pear php-mbstring libapache2-mod-php php-common php-phpseclib php-mysql`

and phpmyadmin is ready.